# Using Lists to Remove First Occurence of a Duplicate Character

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that will, when given a string, remove the first ocurrence of a duplicate character. But there is one detail that trips me up: nonconsecutive characters are not repeats. Thus, `'bookkeeper'` would be `'bokeper'`, but my function spits out `'bokepr'`. How can I fix this? Here is my function.

```
def remove_repeat(message):
    placeholder = [] #The spot that our answer will be built up in
    seen_chars = [] #The place that will hold our seen characters
    for c in message:
        if c not in seen_chars:
            seen_chars.append(c)
        if c not in placeholder:
            placeholder.append(c)
    result = ""
    for c in placeholder:
        result = result + c
    return result
```

Comment: Creating a string from a list of characters should be done with `''.join()`

Comment: Your code doesn't remove the first occurrence of a character, but rather all occurrences but the first one, so I'm a bit confused what you are actually trying to achieve.  What are the expected results for "eetee" and "eeettteee"?

Comment: What should happen for three consecutive characters? For example, should "boooo" become "booo" or "bo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_repeat(message):
    result = []
    curr = None
    for c in message:
        if c != curr:
            curr = c
            result.append(c)

    return "".join(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` to replace all consecutive runs of characters by only a single occurrence (which seems to be what you are trying to do):

```
>>> "".join(k for k, it in itertools.groupby("bookkeeper"))
'bokeper'
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is similar to Dyno Fu's but rather than using a variable to store the previous character we iterate in parallel over two copies of the string data, offset by one position, using the `zip` function. To create the offset data we convert a copy of the string to a list & prepend `None` to it since we can't put a `None` object into a string.

```
def remove_repeat(msg):
    return ''.join([d for c, d in zip([None] + list(msg), msg) if d != c])

print(remove_repeat('bookkeeper'))
```

**output**

```
bokeper
```

Building a string using a list comprehension and then using `.join` to convert the result into a string is a fairly standard idiom in Python since it's more efficient than repeated string concatenation. Modern versions of Python have optimised string concatenation for smallish strings, but you will see a marked difference with strings longer than a 100 or so characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another solution using regular expressions. It is a bit unclear whether something like "booo" should become "bo" (remove all but one of the duplicates) or "boo" (remove one duplicate). So here's both solutions:

Remove one duplicate:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'bookkeeperrrr'
>>> re.sub(r'(.)(\1+)', r'\2', s)
'bokeperrr'
```

We are looking for any character which is duplicated at least twice, and then substitute a match of that pattern with the match minus one of the duplicate characters.

Remove all but one duplicate:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.)(\1+)', r'\1', s)
'bokeper'
```

Same logic here, but we substitute with just one of the duplicated characters.

If "any character" is too general, replace the dot in the regular expression with any characters class you like, `[a-zA-Z]` for example.